# Kotlin Custom OnClickListener Interface

Tags: android, kotlin

I came across this custom OnClickListener interface in [this Udacity project](https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-mars-real-estate/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/marsrealestate/overview/PhotoGridAdapter.kt) while learning Kotlin.  I understand what it's doing but I don't understand how it does it.  Can someone please explain the code to me?

```
/**
 * Custom listener that handles clicks on [RecyclerView] items.  Passes the [MarsProperty]
 * associated with the current item to the [onClick] function.
 * @param clickListener lambda that will be called with the current [MarsProperty]
 */
class OnClickListener(val clickListener: (marsProperty:MarsProperty) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(marsProperty:MarsProperty) = clickListener(marsProperty)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely a hack from before Kotlin 1.4 to allow a pseudo-interface to be constructed with a lambda. Before Kotlin 1.4, you could only use [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions) with Java interfaces. In Kotlin if you defined an interface, you could only create an instance of it by fully implementing it, for example:

```
interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(marsProperty: MarsProperty)
}

val myImplementation = object: OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(marsProperty: MarsProperty) {
        // do something with marsProperty
    }
}
```

But if this had been an interface defined in Java, you were allowed to do this:

```
val myImplementation = OnClickListener { marsProperty ->
    // do something with marsProperty
}
```

By creating a function property in the constructor of this class, it makes the constructor able to be used with [trailing lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas), looking exactly like that second code block. The downside is that it is no longer an interface, so there is less flexibility for the ways it can be used. You still can't use trailing lambda syntax when passing the interface to a function such as `setOnClickListener()`, so it will look something like one of these, depending on how you choose to define the setter (as a function or property:

```
someView.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener { marsProperty ->
    // do something with marsProperty
})

// or

someView.onClickListener = OnClickListener { marsProperty ->
    // do something with marsProperty
}
```

And you can't make some multi-purpose class implement the interface, because there is no interface. For instance, some people use the pattern of making an Android Activity implement a click listener interface and passing the activity instance itself as the listener to the various views.

In Kotlin 1.4, you can now define interfaces as functional by prepending with `fun`. Then SAM conversion will work with them just like with interfaces defined in Java.

```
fun interface OnClickListener {
    funonClick(marsProperty: MarsProperty)
}

val myImplementation = OnClickListener { marsProperty ->
    // do something with marsProperty
}

// or

someView.setOnClickListener { marsProperty ->
    // do something with marsProperty
}
```

Comment: That's a great full answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It can be written like this:

```
class OnClickListener {
    val clickListener: (marsProperty: MarsProperty) -> Unit//function type variable which accepts parameter of MarsProperty type

    constructor(_clickListener: (marsProperty: MarsProperty) -> Unit) {//constructor of class
        clickListener = _clickListener
    }

    fun onClick(marsProperty: MarsProperty) {
        clickListener(marsProperty)//calling of clickListener with parameter of marsProperty
    }
}
```

`clickListener` is a function type variable which accepts parameter of MarsProperty type and returns nothing as result.

`(marsProperty: MarsProperty) = clickListener(marsProperty)` is a single expression function.

`OnClickListener(val clickListener: (marsProperty:MarsProperty) -> Unit)` is declaring of primary constructor.

You can read about function types [here](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-programmer-dictionary-function-type-vs-function-literal-vs-lambda-expression-vs-anonymous-edc97e8873e), about single expression functions [here](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/languages/kotlin/part-17-single-expression-functions), about types of constructors [here](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/constructors).